# VB.Net Login Box testing

Tags: vb.net

I'm learning VB and have made a 'login' box I have searched google for bits and pieces and through my textbook.
I just want you guys to look and tell me if it is good code or not...

I have tested it and it works.. so i know that much does it look 'professional' or dodgy ?

```
Public Class mainLogin
    Private Sub mainLogin_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' selects the username box when form loads
        txtUsername.Select()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnLogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
        If txtUsername.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Username field is empty.")
            txtUsername.Select()
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If txtPassword.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Password field is empty.")
            txtPassword.Select()
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If txtPassword.Text.Length < 8 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Password length must be more then 8 characters.")
            txtPassword.Clear()
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If txtUsername.Text = "PavleS" Then
            If txtPassword.Text = "Password11" Then
                MessageBox.Show("Success!")

                ' Do something fancy here..
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Bad Password!")
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Bad Username!")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ' clears username and password fields
        txtPassword.Text = ""
        txtUsername.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtPassword_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtPassword.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            ' If Enter on the keyboard is pressed it will preform 
            ' the same action as clicking the login button
            btnLogin.PerformClick()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rewrite what you've tried to do: 
1. Use String.IsNullOrEmpty to test if textbox is empty 
2. Use Focus() instead of Select() 
3. Avoid calling an event from another one. If 2 events are to do the same thing, move all the logic in a private method and call the method from both events.(*in reference to your code in txtPassword.KeyDown()*).

```
Private Sub mainLogin_Shown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)   Handles MyBase.Shown

    ' selects the username box when form loads
    txtUsername.Focus()

End Sub


Private Sub btnLogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click


    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUsername.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Username field is empty.")
        txtUsername.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPassword.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Password field is empty.")
        txtPassword.Focus()
        Exit Sub

    Else If txtPassword.Text.Length < 8 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Password length must be more then 8 characters.")
        txtPassword.Clear()
        Exit Sub
    End If


    If txtUsername.Text = "PavleS" Then

        If txtPassword.Text = "Password11" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Success!")

            '
            ' Do something fancy here..
            '
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Bad Password!")
        End If

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Bad Username!")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ' clears username and password fields
    txtPassword.Clear()
    txtUsername.Clear()

End Sub


Private Sub txtPassword_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) _
    Handles txtPassword.KeyDown

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then

        '
        ' If Enter on the keyboard is pressed it will preform 
        ' the same action as clicking the login button
        '
        PerformClick()

    End If

End Sub

  Private Sub PerformClick()
        '' Perform your logic here
  End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, so for the 'PerformClick()' your saying to keep that as its own 'press enter check' sub instead of keeping in that txtPassword sub ?

Comment: Yes, avoid calling an event in another event. So, put all the logic in the `PerformClick method` and then call it in your `btnLogin_Click()` and `txtPassword_KeyDown()`

Comment: Hey Nadeem, I was just testing and when the program starts the txtUsername doesnt start 'selected' the login button does instead ?

Comment: Go in your design view, and go to `VIEW > Tab Order` from your tool options, and arrange your controls in order you wish it to focus, which is the best way of defining your controls order.

Comment: Else you can simply move all the code from the mainLogin_Load() to mainLogin_Shown() as in the answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38330/discussion-between-nadeem-mk-and-pavle-stojanovic)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the coding style, usually you don't store your password in the source code as plaintext (decompliation will reveal it). A common approach is to *hash* the password beforehand and store the hash in the sourcecode. This will make it much more difficult to reverse-engineer the password.

Also, you should not give accurate information on *what* is wrong with the login credentials, but moreover say

> The supplied username / password do not match
>   or similar.

For multiple users you should use

```
Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

and associated methods,, instead of endless if-clauses.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense so 'keepem' guessing which one is wrong LOL....
I was eventually going to connect to a database using SQL...i think...don't know yet